# Querying Smart Contract using its ABI and Ether.js in React

Tags: reactjs, smartcontracts, abi, ethers.js

I have a contract deployed to mainnet. I have a javascript file which exports the functions so they could be called by other  files. I have a button that calls `getOwnerOfToken` from my react. When I click on the button nothing happens and nothing is logged. I understand that since this is a view read-only method I only need the provider (metamask). Before accessing the application I validate the user so metamask is detected using `window.ethereum`.

```js
// Gallery.js (a react component)
import React from "react";
import { getOwnerOfToken } from "../services/nftcontract";

class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
     //constructor stuff here
  }


  // called by onClick of a button in react
  handleProfileChange = selected(selectedIndex) => {
      getOwnerOfToken(selectedIndex).then((address) => {
      this.setState({ currentSelectionnOwner: address });
      console.log(this.state.currentSelectionnOwner);
     });
   }

  render() { 
      // a button with the callback attached to onclick
      <button onClick=onClick={() => this.handleProfileChange ()}>Change Profile</button>
  }
}
```

Here is the service/nftcontract.js file that was imported above

```js
import { ethers } from "ethers";

// Note: the full abi was copied from the ABI section found in etherscan. 
// This is a simplified version for this example
const abi = [
  {
    inputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "tokenId", type: "uint256" }],
    name: "ownerOf",
    outputs: [{ internalType: "address", name: "", type: "address" }],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
];

const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const address = global.config.addresses.collections.genesis;
const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, provider);

const getOwnerOfToken = async (tokenid) => {
  return await contract.ownerOf(tokenid);
};

export { getOwnerOfToken };
```

**EDIT with Solution:**
I found the problem! It was a metamask injection issue. On startup an async call would occur before metamask could inject into the window. This did not happen all the time in my case but it would occur when first visiting the app. So to solve that issue I moved all the variables inside the async function like so. So whenever an async call is made a new contract instance is created.

```js
const getOwnerOfToken = async (tokenid) => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  const address = global.config.addresses.collections.genesis; 
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, provider);
  const ownerAddress = await contract.ownerOf(tokenid);
  //   console.log(`EFService: ${ownerAddress}`);
  return ownerAddress;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to call the `getSigner()` on the `provider` like this

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const address = global.config.addresses.collections.genesis;
const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);
```

`getSigner()`
from official docs

> Returns a JsonRpcSigner which is managed by this Ethereum node, at addressOrIndex. If no addressOrIndex is provided, the first account (account #0) is used.

You can read it here https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/

Also, make sure you are passing the correct address in the `ethers.contract`

ps: You should switch from classes to functional components in react

Comment: No the signer is if you want to write to the contract. If I am using a `view ` read-only function then provider is fine. This is stated in docs (https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/example/#example-erc-20-contract--methods) show 2 ways to connect either provider or signer. `// Read-Only; By connecting to a Provider.` Where as ` Read-Write; By connecting to a Signer`. I think using React classes vs functional depend on the use-cases. If you are storing a lot of state and want to program in a reactive way Classes is the way to go.

Comment: Have you tried using signer tho?

Comment: Hi Yes I tried signer and that did not work. I found out the issue and updated it with an answer. It was a metamask injection problem. The async call would trigger before metamask fully injected into the browser so window.ethereum would fail on startup. I instead moved all the variables inside the method to fix the problem (see edited post).